# I am getting error while trying to add Java Request Sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While trying to add java request Sampler in Jmeter, I am getting below error in the logs:

```
 2017-08-30 17:16:28,374 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/qpid/url/BindingURL

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]

at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]

at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.config.gui.JavaConfigGui.classOk 

 (JavaConfigGui.java:269) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:3.2 r1790748]
```

Please suggest how could I remove this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class `org/apache/qpid/url/BindingURL`.

Class can be found in [qpid](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.qpid/qpid-common/0.30/) common 0.30 jar

You need to put your jar in JMeter's lib folder.